# How is HCF (c, d) = HCF (d, r), where c = dq +r (by Euclid's division lemma)?

Tags: arithmetic

I read this in a math textbook, stated as obvious fact. I cannot wrap my head around why this works. I understood the division lemma, and also got the algorithm to work: but the proof of *why* the algorithm works, just said "because of the equation" that I put in the question.

Could you please elaborate on why it works?

Answer (score 1):

1) Suppose that $m$ divides $c$ and $d$. Then $m$ divides $c-dq$, so $m$ divides $d$ and $r$.

2) Suppose that $m$ divides $d$ and $r$. Then since $c=dq+r$, we get that $m$ divides $c$ and $d$.

Thus the set of common divisors of $c$ and $d$ is **exactly the same** as the set of common divisors of $d$ and $r$.

In particular, the **greatest** common divisors are the same (and the second greatest, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ If $\ n\mid d\ $ then $\ n\mid dq+r\!\iff\! n\mid r.\,$ Thus $\,\{d,\,dq+r\}\, $ and $\,\{d,r\}\, $ have the same set $\,S\,$ of *common* divisors $\,n,\,$ so they have the same *greatest* common divisor $( = \max\, S).$

Answer (score 0):

Let the HCF of $c$ and $d$ be $k$.

Converting the given equation to modulo k

$$dq+r ≡ 0 \mod k$$

since $c$ is divisible by $k$. But $d$ is also divisble by $k$ and thus,

$$r ≡  0 \mod k$$

implying $r$ is divisble by $k$.

Therefore $k$ divides both $r$ and $d$ and hence must divide $HCF(r,d)=m$

Similarly it can be shown that $m$ must divide $k$. Thus $k=m$